# Why are incorrect type assignments allowed in Dart?

Tags: dart, dartium

I know that types are pretty much optional with Dart, but if I choose to specify the variable type, I expect an assignment like  `int i = "abc"` to throw an error in runtime. However neither that nor any of the following throw an error, they just ignore the type cast.

```
  String str     = "test";
  int integer    = 5;
  double decimal = 1.5;
  List list      = [1,2,3];

  String s = decimal;   print(s);  // 1.5
  int i    = str;       print(i);  // test
  double d = list;      print(d);  // [1, 2, 3]
  List l   = integer;   print(l);  // 5
```

In [this tutorial](http://insights.dice.com/2013/03/06/how-to-program-dart-tutorial-two/) I found, it says:

> But the snippet below generates an error because the compiler identifies b as an int that is wrongly being assigned a double value. This is type-checking in action, and one of the many ways that Dart improves on JavaScript.
>
> int b=7898765;
>
> b = 9.8; // ERROR Can't assign double to int

However, that code doesn't generate an error for me either when using Dartium or when using `<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`.

If I do `var i = "abc" + 1.5`, it throws an error, so why doesn't a type misassignment do the same? Is this an oversight or is it a design choice? If the latter, what's the reasoning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This answer is Dart 1.x only

In Dart type annotations are just ignored when run in production mode (default). If you run in checked mode types are checked. If you call a non-existing method on an instance an exception is still thrown.

```
var i = "abc" + 1.5
```

the `+` operator (method) obviously does a type check on the argument and throws because it doesn't non-string values.

For JS generated from Dart you can configure the `$dart2js` transformer to produce "checked-mode" output by adding

```
transformers:
- $dart2js:
    checked: true
```

to your `pubspec.yaml` file (for more `$dart2js` options see [Configuring the Built-in dart2js Transformer for Pub](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer.html)).
This only takes effect if you build using `pub build`. If you use `dart2js` directly to generate JS pass the `-c` flag to create checked-mode output.

For code run on the server VM also pass the `-c` flag like

```
dart -c your_script.dart
```

In your question you didn't provide any information about how you run your Dart scripts or how you generate JS.

In this simple [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dc54b54f65a6bbadbea9) the editor shows errors from static analysis, which is another use-case for adding type annotations.

Comment: Thank you! Checked mode is good to know about, I'll use it when developing. I'm now just trying to start Dartium with the checked flag to see what it does (on windows so it's giving me some attitude). As for how I generate the JS, right now I'm using Dartium because I hate debugging through generated code but normally I just use Chrome Dev Editor.

Comment: If you use WebStorm for example, checked mode is always the default when debugging in Dartium or a server side script.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it. Do you need more information?

Comment: While your answer's helpful and it's good to know I can debug my code using checked mode, my question was more about the language design decision. I don't understand why they chose not to make a type misassignment an error by default, as it seems like it should be. I still +1'd you, but that was more what I was curious about.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to know if your question is fully answered or if you just forgot to accept ;-). Dart has an unique design/philosophy. Here is for example a paper from one of the Dart language designers http://bracha.org/pluggableTypesPosition.pdf. See also https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/ As I wrote in my answer, type annotations are generally ignored at runtime. This is a basic Dart design decision. Checked mode is a development tool that allows to verify that type annotations actually conform to the actual types assigned at runtime.

Comment: See also http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/10/21/wrapping-my-head-around-optional-typing/

Answer (score 0):

Dart 2.6 rejects this code.

```
A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'
```

https://dartpad.dev/10ebe4bb74a11fe6e68efb351af40d1a

I've also tested with a `Map<String, dynamic>` (in order to better understand the [JSON deserialization pattern](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes))

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'str': 'test',
    'integer': 5,
    'decimal': 1.5,
    'list': [1,2,3]
  };

  String s = map['decimal'];   print(s);  // JSDouble not String
  int i    = map['str'];       print(i);  // JSString not int
  double d = map['list'];      print(d);  // JSArray not double
  List l   = map['integer'];   print(l);  // JSInt not List
}
```

https://dartpad.dev/7bc355b3b7779d2b37e1aae2b6def050

and this also fails at runtime, giving errors such as

```
TypeError: 1.5: type 'JSDouble' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```